# update column of table1 with sum of duplicated fields

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I would like to update all field of table1 which refer to equal fields in table 2 with it' sum:
Example: table1  has

```
 Fieldname  |   amount
 -------------------------
    a       |       200
    a       |       300 
    b       |       50
    b       |       150
```

now I would like to have the sum of amounts where Fieldname is equal copied into it's related field of table2 so it look in table 2 like

```
 Fieldname  |   SumAmount
 -------------------------
    a       |       500
    b       |       200
```

Comment: where is the expected output?

Comment: Why do you need a new table for this anyway? Unless you want to delete the table1 you dont need a new table. Just use the select statement.

Answer (score 1):

If fieldNames already exist in table2, you can do:

```
UPDATE table2 t2
INNER JOIN
(SELECT fieldName, SUM(amount) as total
 FROM table1
 GROUP BY fieldName
) T1 ON t1.fieldName = t2.fieldName
SET t2.sumAmount = t1.total
```

Otherwise, you will have to INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (fieldName,sumAmount)
SELECT fieldName, SUM(amount)
FROM table1
GROUP BY fieldName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table2(Fieldname, SumAmount)
SELECT Fieldname, SUM(amount) 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY Fieldname;
```

Comment: wow, so quick...and so easy to do ( being a newbie ;-) ) Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table2 SET SumAmount= 
(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table1 GROUP BY fieldname)x 
WHERE table2.fieldname=x.fieldname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET 
    t1.amount = t2.SumAmount
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Fieldname = t2.Fieldname
```